# Run time plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I need to create a graph that compares two functions, and places the rows read on the X axis and the execution time on the Y axis.

At the moment I have created the first function, to calculate the first graph with it.

The script I have made is this:

```
def get_column_pandas(path, column):
    pandas = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=';')
    columna = list(pandas.iloc[:, column])


get_column_pandas(path_artists, 2)
fin = default_timer()
print(fin - inicio)
```

This returns me a list of the values ​​that I have to show in the x-axis (columna variable) and the total execution time of the function.

But at this point I don't know how I can graph it.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a few things you may need to do. I suggest to start with a graph of one function,  time=f(rows) . Another couple of things: it is not a good idea to call a data frame "pandas" and also your function should have a return columna so you populate your x-axis list like, for example,  x=get_columna_pandas(path_artist,2)

Comment: Please don't use the name `pandas` for the variable to store your dataframe.  Use something like `df = pd.read_csv(....)` and then `df[column].plot()`.   See also [pandas' plotting tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html)